# Evaluating Limits at Infinity

Tags: calculus

I'm working on an assignment for calculus and I'm having some problems with evaluating limits at infinity. I can solve most problems but I'm unsure of what to do when there's a square root in the problem. I have two square root problems, but I think if I get one I should be able to do the other, here's the one that's giving me troubles,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x}$$

For the first question this is what I've done so far,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x}{x^2-2x-2x}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x}{x^2-4x}$$

And at this point I'm confused as what to do, I normally use the power rules so I got,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1}}$$

After checking WolfRamAlpha it says that the correct answer is $-1$, can someone show me how to properly do these types of questions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that you multiplied the top and bottom incorrectly.  You should have
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x}{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x}= 
\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x}{(x^2 - 2x)- x^2} =
-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x}{2x}
$$
Note at this point that if the limit is non-zero, it should be negative.  Now, try dividing the top and bottom by $x$.  You should have
$$
-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x}{2x} \cdot \frac{1/x}{1/x}= 
-\frac{\sqrt{1-(2/x)}+1}{2}
$$
What happens to this fraction as $x \to \infty$?

Answer (score 2):

the last term of denominator in the second step should be $x^2$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x}+x}{x^2-2x-x^2}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}+1}{-2}=\frac{\sqrt{1-0}+1}{-2}=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake in the first step, the denominator should be $x^{2}-2x-x^{2}$. So you get the limit of $\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-2x}+x}{-2x}$, from which you can apply your following steps to get -1

Answer (score 0):

Setting $\displaystyle \frac1x=h,$

$$F=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac1{\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac h{\sqrt{1-2h}-1}$$

Rationalizing the denominator, 
$$F=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h(\sqrt{1-2h}+1)}{{1-2h}-1}$$

As $h\to0,h\ne0$ cancelling $h,$ $$ F=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1-2h}+1}{-2}=\frac{1+1}{-2}$$